# how to get wehere variable data laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

```
$data = Models::all();
$new_data = $data::where('category','tree')->get();
return view('backend.view',compact('data','new_data));
```

can i make $data to type data by other categories?

Error
Using $this when not in object context

Comment: Note really sure what you're asking, something like `$new_data = Models::where('category','tree')->get();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$data = Models::all();
$new_data = $data->where('category','tree');
```